# How do i call a method from a String array Hashmap

Tags: java

I have this block of code, and I'm a bit of a rookie to Java and wonder is it possible to call a void method from an hashmap.

eg

```
HashMap<String, String[]> responses = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String[] temp5 ={ " Assignment 1", "Assignment 2"};
    responses.put("what is the current assignment", Writer());
```

the void function is

```
Void Writer(){

File file = new File("data.txt");


try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(newFileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true))) {



        System.out.println(" enter what you want to teach me");
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
        // for(String line : lines){
         wr.write(lines);
        wr.write("\n");

        wr.newLine();
        // }
        // }
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" cannot write to file " + file.toString());
    }

    return null;

}
```

Comment: What is `return null;` doing in your so-called void function? Does that method even compile? And what's the purpose of calling that method? You can only put a `String[]` as value in a map.

Comment: What you are trying to do in your code makes no sense whatsoever. Please explain more about what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: The `put(...)` method of your `HashMap` expects the second parameter to be a `String[]` and since `Writer()` returns `void` this code won't compile

Comment: This code won't compile for many reasons: `Void` instead of `void`, `return` statement with a value in a void method, caling a void method where an array of strings is expected. And an `enter code here` which I'm sure should be in a comment or removed completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am creating a void function which writes to a file. So the void function is

```
    public static void Writer() {

    File file = new File("data.txt");
    try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            file.getAbsoluteFile(), true))) { // Creates a writer object
                                                // called wr
                                                // file.getabsolutefile
                                                // takes the filename and
                                                // keeps on storing the old
                                                // data

        System.out.println(" enter what you want to teach me");
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
         wr.write(lines);
        wr.write("\n");

        wr.newLine();

        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" cannot write to file " + file.toString());
    }


}
```

and the hashmap function is

```
HashMap<String, String[]> responses = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    String[] temp0 = { "What does that suggest to you?", "I see.",
            "I'm not sure I understand you fully.", "Can you elaborate?",
            "That is quite interesting." };
    responses.put("NOTFOUND", temp0);


    String[] temp1 = { "I'm sorry I do not know, but can you help me learn?" };
    responses.put("sure", temp1);

     String[] temp2 = { "I am sorry to hear you are *.",
            "How long have you been *?",
            "Do you believe it is normal to be *?", "Do you enjoy being *?" };
    responses.put("i am", temp2);
    responses.put("i'm", temp2);

    String[] temp3 = { "Tell me more about such feelings.",
            "Do you often feel *?", "Do you enjoy feeling *?",
            "Why do you feel that way?" };
    responses.put("i feel", temp3);

   //String [] temp8 = {Writer()};

    String[] temp4 = {"is that all?"};

    responses.put("now",  temp4);
      responses.put("now",Writer() );

    String[] temp5 ={ " Assignment 1", "Assignment 2"};
    responses.put("what is the current assignment", temp5);

    String[] keywords = { "i think", "i am", "i'm", "i feel","sure","learn","done","now","what is the current assignment" };
```

So the purpose is to call the Writer method each instance where any keyword is found. In this case the keyword is "now" and the writer function is called to write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call methods inside HashMap `put`, but that method has to return whatever your `HashMap` stores.

In your case `HashMap<String, String[]>` your method **must** return `String[]`

Imagine a method

```
public String[] fakeData() {
   String[] result;
   //some logic that initializes result
   return result;
}
```

So you could call it:

```
responses.put("Foo", fakeData());
```

A complete example:

```
public class Test {

    public String[] fakeData() {
        String[] x = new String[5];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            x[i] = "Data: " + rand.nextInt(50);
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        HashMap<String,String[]> responses = new HashMap<>();
        responses.put("Foo", t.fakeData());

        for(Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : responses.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey());
            System.out.println("Value: ");
            for(String s : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println("\t" + s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how is it possible to return a String[ ] from a void Writer( )?